# windows 8 android usb driver

Tags: android, windows-8

I have installed Windows 8 release preview 
and I cant install android USB drivers, it says this:

[image: Screenshot]

and

"the third party INF does not contain digital signature information"

what to do?

Comment: Could it be that the driver is not certified for windows 8, and you need to configure win 8 to allow unsigned drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue a while ago. Seeing that the USB driver hasn't been updated since, the simple (and probably unsatifying) answer is revert back to windows 7. I've seen some scetchy drivers around but not for your device.

Windows 8 is still in preview/developer stage and I doubt we'll see proper drivers until it's closer to release. Just keep checking the SDK Manager and try again when the USB driver has an update.

Answer (score 2):

Disable device signature confirmation on Win8 and follow the guide here. www.androidsim.net/2009/08/how-to-1-how-to-install-usb-driver-on.html

Answer (score 0):

Disable driver signing
Run Command Prompt as an administrator
Paste and run the following commands:
bcdedit -set loadoptions DISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING ON

or:
Win+c => parameters => Shift + restart and then like a links below...
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/windows-startup-settings-including-safe-mode

http://www.fotoclubinc.com/blog/how-to-disable-driver-signature-enforcement-to-allow-installation-of-windows-7-printer-drivers-on-windows-8/

Answer (score 0):

I had the some problem, and this how I fixed it.

On windows 8, **Hold any SHIFT** on your keyboard and Click **Settings** on the **right corner** of your PC or laptop, than the Menu bar of **Settings** will appear, than click **Power**, than click restart

You will see the **Choose an Option**, than you choose **Troubleshoot**
Under Troubleshoot choose **Advanced options**, and Under **Advanced options** choose **Startup Settings**, than **click Restart**, than **press 7**. After your PC or Laptop restart your **will be able to Install Android ADB Drivers** or any Drivers

I hope this will help you too

Answer (score -2):

BLU VIVO AIR had same issue.  I blogged about getting the generic google usb driver to install here with step by step and no funny links or ads - http://www.devfish.net/post/2015/07/20/android-usb-adb-drivers-for-blu-phones-vivo-air.aspx .  Windows 8.1 ....

Use a USB cable to connect the Windows PC and your phone .
Open up Device manager.  You'll see the BLU VIVO AIR show up in "Other Devices" as unavailable.

Download and install the Google Generic USB Driver from  http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#top .
Note down and remember the location where you install the  google driver to.

Right mouse the BLU VIVO AIR, select Update Driver Software…

Select "Browse for driver software on your computer"

Navigate to where you installed the Google USB Driver software

Select "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer"

Select "Show all devices"

Select "Have Disk"

Navigate to where you installed the Google USB driver, select the android_winusb.inf file

In the Update Driver Software - VIVO AIR dialog select "Android ADB Interface"

Ignore the "Update Driver Warning" message.

You will now see the Android Device -> Android ADB Interface in Device Manager, and VIVO AIR will be gone from "Other Devices". You should now also be able to turn on things like USB/Mass Storage Mode on the phone so you can view files from Windows Explorer as well as debug to the device.