# Install Android driver for Windows 8

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, windows-8.1, lg

UPDATE:
It's fixed!  It turns out there was a driver on the LG site that, once downloaded, fixed the issue.

I've tried using both folders, including the usb_driver directory, but none of these directories work.  It always gives me the same issue. As seen below, the 'ADB Interface' driver is most likely my android driver.

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082622/windows-8-android-usb-driver) response to a very similar question, but none of these answers seem like they will work.  I have an LG G4 phone and windows 8 on a Dell laptop.  I would like to try running my application on my phone instead of an emulator, except whenever I plug in my phone, with developer mode turned on, I cannot seem to find or use my device on Android Studio.  I run the application and get to the dialog that asks me to choose the device on which to run the application, but my device still does not show up.  I have updated several packages on the SDK manager and tried manually installing the driver that's supposed to be in /extras/google/usb_driver/, but nothing has worked. Has anyone here been able to get their application running on their device while using Windows 8?

Comment: I think you should install usb driver for LG G4 phone.

Comment: I think it might already be installed, but even when I try to install it again it won't help.

Comment: This question should be moved to SuperUser, this is not a programming question it is a tool question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that USB debugging mode inside developer option is turned ON. After that you should see a dialog in your mobile to allow that computer for Debugging purpose. You can check always allow if it is your own PC

Comment: I checked that. It was set to ON the whole time.

Comment: does this problem occur only in your PC or only in your mobile? I mean, did you try working with other devices?